# MVC 3 Shared Template Editor: Set default value for Create but not Edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, editorfor

I would like to set the default value for an 'EditorFor' on my Shared Template, but only on the Crate method and not the Edit method.  How would I do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you can do this other than setting an EditorFor template and using `EditorFor` for the Create method, and `TextboxFor` on the Edit method (or vice versa).

You can still extend `TextboxFor` with custom CSS if needed, but it will probably not be quite as pretty as EditorFor.

Another option would be to build a TextboxFor razor template (if you're using MVC3 and Razor) and load it in as a `@helper { }` (still passing the model).
[see Scott Gu's post on this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

Comment: What I'm doing presently is using Javascript to check the Model value, and if it's empty set the default value of the control: ` if ('@Model.EntryDate' == '') { $('#EntryDate').val(currentDate.getMonth()+1 + '/' + currentDate.getDate() + '/' + currentDate.getYear()); }`

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day I decided this should be done in the controller, on my Create/Edit actions.